# Get only one field of an array returned by a function

Tags: php, shortcut

When I have a function returning an array, I would like to get only one field, using the key.

I usually do this in 2 lines, like that :

```
$myArray = getArray();
$myField = $myArray[0];
```

Is there a way, a shortcut or something, to do this in one line ?

Per example something like that :

```
$myField = getArray()[0];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need PHP > 5.4

```
PHP 5.4.0 offers a wide range of new features:
...
Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0].
```

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: Thanks, I knew I have seen (and used) something like this, but on a different server whick isn't on PHP 4. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

on PHP 5.4 version or greater than that you can do

```
$myField = getArray()[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're locked into a PHP version earlier than 5.4, you could do your own quick function enabling you to do this in one line later on:

```
function getElement($array, $index)
{
   return $array[$index];
}
```

ie

```
echo getElement(getArray(), 0);
```